# VueJS find element by key

Tags: vue.js

I've just wanted to know if it is possible to find a DOM element by the key attribute of vue?
I'm currently working with a list. I'm displaying it via v-for directive on a div. I'm binding the key with the index of the elements.

```
v-for="(apk, index) in project.apks" v-bind:key="index"
```

It would really help me if i could compute something for each of these elements as soon as they are fetch from my server and displayed. It's just parsing a file and looking for keyword, and accordingly choosing a css class for the items.

The problem is I dont know how to call a method for each of these elements as soon as they are added to the DOM. They are a lot of html events but i couldnt find one representing the object beeing inserted to dom :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is I dont know how to call a method for each of these elements as soon as they are added to the DOM. They are a lot of html events but i couldnt find one representing the object beeing inserted to dom :(

You can create a new component with your `v-for` and just call the [created()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) hook.

---

### Example

```
/* On your main function */
<div v-for="apk in project.apks">
    <apk :data="apk"></apk>
</div>

/* On your 'apk' component */
export default {
    props: [ "data" ],
    created() {
        console.log("Created !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that's actually pretty clever. Too bad though that there isn't a created html event that we could use with vue as so: @created="doStuff(index)"

Comment: Actually you can emit cutom event in created hook of your apk element: `this.$emit('created')` and catch it like you described above.

Answer (score 27):

The purpose of `key` is not selecting element. Even if it can be done, don't do it.

The proper way to do it is by using [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs).

for example, add `ref` attribute to your html like this

`v-for="(apk, index) in project.apks" v-bind:key="index" :ref="'sample-ref-'+index"`

and then in your methods, you can get the DOM using `this.$refs['sample-ref-0']`,`this.$refs['sample-ref-1']` and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ho, you responded before I did, here a JSFiddle if OP wants to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/qg5rjp2j/11/

Comment: Thanks, I almost did that. I used :id=" 'apk' + index ", which I assume is the same. I can get elements after server fetch (with a timeout so vue has time to add them to DOM before adding css class) with for loop document.getElementById('apk' + i) and do my stuff. ;)

Comment: if you use `:ref` in a `v-for`, the refs are stored as arrays, so I think even if you use a unique label for each item, you'll end up with a bunch of one element arrays, so need `this.$refs['sample-ref-0'][0]`?

Comment: @patricksurry nope. it's not going to be a bunch of one element arrays. you can try it out.

Comment: hmm, I did `<div v-for="e in session.events" :key="e.id" :ref="'event-' + e.id">...` and my `this.$refs` ends up as a object with each key pointing to an array with one item. This is `vue@2.5.16`

Comment: @JacobGoh If you look at the JSFiddle it says `this.$refs.myElement2[0].style.color = 'red';`. The `[0]` part means it's a (single element) array.

The documentation also states that refs in a v-for will become an array: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: This will be very different depending on Vue version. Vue2 creates an array indeed. An if you use different refs, it will create multiple arrays. Mix this with v-show or v-if and you get a bunch of empty arrays. No good. Now in Vue3 it does not create arrays for you. Instead if you bind  a v-for, it will take a function as an argument and it is up to you to create an array of refs. See documentation for details.

Answer (score 9):

I found that if you give the 'ref' the same name in a v-for, like this:

```
<div v-for="data in list" :key="data.id" ref="bar"></div>
```

Then you will find they just store in an array called 'bar' and you can visit them by:

```
this.$refs['bar'][index]
```

Answer (score 4):

something like this could allow you to find a component by key :

```
this.$children.forEach(child=>{
 print("child.$vnode.key")
})
```

also use mounted  , as it gets called when the component is added to the dom:

```
mounted:function(){
this.$el.querySelector("#ele1")...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Vue [3.2.47+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414977/refs-inside-v-for-loop-for-vue-v3-2-25-or-above) searchers, you can access elements of a `v-for` array with a `ref` to an array directly: ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)).

```js
const itemRefs = ref([]);
```

```html
<Comp v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
  {{ item }}
  {{ itemRefs[2] }}
</Comp>
```

However, if your v-for is a list of custom components, be sure to [expose any fields or functions you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667783/how-to-use-a-template-ref-on-a-custom-component-in-vue-3-compositon-api) with [defineExpose](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose). ([example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)).

If furthermore you require that the list of refs maintain the same order, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181832/6844235) to be very helpful.